# how to detect keywords with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, syntax-highlighting

I want to write a simple code highlighter in php for java. One of the keywords is "class", and is replaced by `<span class="keyword">class</span>`
The problem is that the class from the span is also marked as a keyword. So i need a regex that says: `"class",and after that not "="` 
it tried with `/class[^=]` but this is totally bullshit. So, how can i create this but not this expressions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the regex for `match 'class' string, but only if it's not followed by '='` task is more-o-less easy to build, using the [negative lookahead](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) assertion:

```
/class(?!=)/
```

But I'm afraid it's only the beginning of the story. Should you match words like `subclass` and `classless`, for example? Probably not, so the keyword should be wrapped into `\b` (word boundary anchors):

```
/\bclass\b(?!=)/
```

Comment: hmm youre absolutely right, actually i have this problem with number to. thank you. so ?! means the same as "not" ? and what does () mark?

Comment: `()` is used just to delimit a lookahead pattern in this case. `(?!<expr>)` matches a position in the string that's not a beginning of the substring matched by `<expr>`.

Comment: @T_01 A negative lookahead is not the same as a negated character class. `[^=]` will require the match of one item that is anything but an equal symbol.  `(?!=)` will keep the cursor in the same position, and will return true if there is not an equal symbol following that position, and will return false if there IS an equal symbol, but will not consume the next position, nor break if there is not a next position.